# Line chart animation in svg using jquery

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I want to do line chart (path animation) individually not whole chart area. Please refer below JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2LEyb/

currently i have implemented the animation for whole chart area  i.e. area rect initially zero and then i will increase the width step by step. it will affect other charts because column chart also with in chart area but it will do animation  link line. Please refer below code snippet currently i have done.

```
 doAnimation: function () {
        var clipRect = $(this.chartObj.gSeriesEle).find("#" + this.chartObj.svgObject.id + "_ChartAreaClipRect");
        $(clipRect).animate(
                                 { width: this.chartObj.model.m_AreaBounds.Width },
                                 {
                                     duration: 2000,

                                     step: function (now, fx) {
                                         $(clipRect).attr("width", now);
                                     }
                                 });
       this.chartObj.model.Animation=false;

    },
```

i need to get the individual "line" path rectangle and then i  want to increase the width of individual line path rectangle step by step in jquery animate instead increasing the width of entire chart area.

how to calculate the rectangle for individual path and then increase the width of rectangle.

```
<g id="container_svg_SeriesGroup_0" transform="translate(144,432)"><path id="container_svg_John_0" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="url(#container_svg_John0Gradient)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M -2454.7999999999997 -125.8888888888889 L 0 0 M 0 0 L 258.40000000000003 -45.77777777777778 M 258.40000000000003 -45.77777777777778 L 516.8000000000001 -11.444444444444445 M 516.8000000000001 -11.444444444444445 L 646 -183.11111111111111 "/></g>
```

Thanks,

Siva